# what are the facilities a Fake Backend provides to the Angular app?

Tags: angular, forms, backend, backendless

With the Fake Backend in Angular, along with saving data from a form, can it be used to display the data at the frontend?
What are the features it has that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using backend technologies you can create the services or API's like create data, retrieve data.

Using frontend technologies you can call this backend API's and pass the data to backend for perform some actions like add, edit, delete etc.. Also, you can design the website or app using frontend technology.

For more information please refer **[this](https://www.conceptatech.com/blog/difference-front-end-back-end-development#:%7E:text=Front%2Dend%20developers%20work%20on,high%2Dfunctioning%20application%20or%20website.)** blog

Comment: It was about "Fake Backend" to be used with Angular, not what is backend.

Comment: Yes you can retrieve the listing data from fake backend also

Comment: Please show the https://www.npmjs.com/package/the-fake-backend plugin to understand fake backend this is the package for creating the fake backend with angular